# D3.js / Javascript Node-Lines pop-up window and color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am working on D3.js and I have a map with lines and nodes. When I come on them with mouse I want them to change color and get thicker and I want a small pop-up window which shows their IDs. 
On HTML for the pop-up there is a function onmouseover.
First question: Is there any function in javascript like onmouseover?
Second question: Is there any way me to change the color and make the lines or nodes thicker when the mouse are on that specific node or line. (I can use JQuery if there is a way in JQuery)

Comment: show some code. It is possible! Yes JS does have an onmouseover functionality.

Comment: var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(Data.nodes)
    ...
    on("mouseover", function(){
        d3.select(this).enter.append("text")
        text(function(d) {return d.ID;})
    });

Comment: that's fine, your comment. the callback recieves a target. you can reference it using <code>this</code>. That shoud pick up your element, then apply whatever you want on your element.

Comment: @Pbd can you show what you mean on the code I posted?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace change wasn't helpful :)

Comment: var node = svg.selectAll(".node") .data(Data.nodes) ... on("mouseover", function(){
   d3.select(this).style("strike","thick"); // sample CSS operation.
}) 

"this" in high likeliness is the element you want to work on

Comment: Feel free to undo it =] Its a heated debate lol http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I will try thanks! @Pbd

Comment: Well, in Canada we use greetings and appreciation a lot :) @AtheistP3ace

Comment: Not looking to start an extended conversation on this. I use them as well in everyday interactions and please don't take the change as a personal affront. Some people believe questions should stick to the issue at hand and others feel its no issue to have these other greetings and thanks in there. I personally feel for others possibly coming from a google search and arriving at a question it should be minimal and to the point but it is only my opinion and means nothing to anyone but me at the end of the day. Like I said feel free to roll it back as it is your question.

Comment: Fluff like "thanks" "hello" et. al don't belong in questions and will be removed, because it's only coincidence that the question has a user attached. That debate's long since been settled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the tooltip I have this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/7NReF/36/

Firstly, create the container for the toolip :

```
 var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr('class','tooltipdiv')
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("a simple tooltip");
```

Then on mouseover set the text to what you want, mousemove, move the tooltip, and mouseout, hide the tooltip :

```
circles.on("mouseover", function(d){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").text(d);})
.on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top",
    (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
.on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
```

As for the nodes, you can either style it directly or add a class and do it all in one. So you only need to change the CSS. So with the above being said, I have implemented both in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/7NReF/37/

Source code :

```js
var w = 500;
var h = 50;

var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(dataset)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle");

circles.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
            return (i * 50) + 25;
        })
       .attr("cy", h/2)
       .attr("r", function(d) {
            return d;
       });
       
       
 var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr('class','tooltipdiv')
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("a simple tooltip");
    
    
circles.on("mouseover", function(d){
d3.select(this).classed('hovernode', true)
return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").text(d);})
.on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top",
    (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
.on("mouseout", function(){
d3.select(this).classed('hovernode', false)
return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
```

```css
.tooltipdiv{
  background:white;
}

.hovernode{
  fill:red;
  stroke:blue;
  stroke-width:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    
</body>
```

I have added the ability to change the border of the nodes

Comment: I found this on internet and found tooltip complicated @thisOneGuy

Comment: its not d3.tooltip. Its just a var called tooltip. Its creating a div and on mouseover changing the text, mousemove, changing the tooltips position and mouseout, hiding the tooltip. What is so complicated ? By the way, try not to put code in the comments, hard to read :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
           .data(Data.nodes)
           .on("mouseover", function(){
           d3.select(this).style("stroke","thick"); // sample CSS operation.
})
```

`this` is the element a `node` in your case which you want to work on.

I would suggest against using jquery. I somehow feel d3 is faster than jquery and can implement similar functionality with greater control.

Comment: var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(thisData.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; }) 
      .style('stroke','red')
      .style("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr('r', 2)

This is a piece of my code, I already have red nodes with radius = 2. I want them to change color, get thicker and show a popup message when I am on them.

Comment: Sorry for the mess it doesn't get this is a piece of code and also doesn't let me to add a screen shot of the code

Answer (score 0):

Okay I wrote a piece of code as an answer to change the color and it works:

```
.on("mouseover", function(){
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("fill", "orange");
})

.on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("fill", "rgb(0, 0, " +(d*10) + ")");
});
```

first .on function makes it orange(you can change the color however you want, second .on makes the original color when you're not on the element anymore.

For pop-up window:

```
.append("title")
.text(function(d){return d;});
```

Comment: you think my code helped you? If it did, please accept it.

Comment: kind of yes but the real code about what I needed is the one I wrote. I wrote the code for you under your answer in the code it is already thick so it doesn't change my elements @Pbd